# how to check two string columns from two different dataframes on partial matching in R?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, merge

I am new to R and struggling with something which may not even be asked correctly but this is how I could articulate it best at this moment. 
I have two different CSV files read into R. `dataA1` contains 481242 rows and 71 columns (i.e. variables) one of which is the conm (i.e. company name). `dataB1` contains 1615 rows for 7 columns (variables) one of which is company.name.

some of 1615 company names from `dataB1` partially or fully match (overlap) with some of the 481242 company names from `dataA1`.

My goal is, to create a column in `dataB1` where I will have 1-s for those companies that are also found in `dataA1` (partially or fully the same name), and with 0-s for those that are not found there.

any ideas how to do this?

to give you a better idea how the data looks like, here is the `dataA1` :

```
1-PAGE LTD
3I GROUP PLC
3I INFOTECH LTD
401 HOLDINGS LTD
4CS HOLDINGS CO LTD
55 STATION INC
600 GROUP PLC (THE)
7DIGITAL GROUP PLC
```

and the column that needs to be matched from `dataB1` :

```
1-Page Ltd
180 Connect Inc
3DLabs Inc., Ltd.
3M France
3U Holdings AG
4Imprint Group Plc
724 Solutions Inc
7days music entertainment AG
```

Comment: Can you give some rule/hints on how you want to perform the partial matching ? Because I'm not even able to do it by hand looking at your example...

Comment: what I mean by partial matching is, that companies with similar but not exactly the same names should be coupled/matched. for instance holdings LTD and holdings AG is basically the same company but one with German version of its name (AG = Ltd) so since the main part of their name overlaps they should be identified as matched pair. 
there may be a way to determine percentage of an overlap for declaring it as matching pair (e.g. 80% or more). it depends on a technique. I've used 80% fuzzy lookup match to perform this task. only problem is the size of a data too big for excel

Answer (score 0):

I do not have enough detail, but I would consider using a flag operation. A flag operator just identifies which values in a vector are present in a corresponding data frame, vector, etc. For your example I would do something like this:

```
dataB1 <- toupper(dataB1)
flag   <- dataB1 %in% dataA1
```

This code will give a `TRUE` if a value is fully matched in dataA1 and a `FALSE` otherwise in the form of a vector.

Comment: Thanks akash87. That sounds good and will be definitely useful for similar tasks. However  this will give TRUE if the value is fully matched.

in my case I need partial match. for example if companies have the same name but with "ltd." or "ltd" at the end or something like "1-page ltd" versus "one-page ltd" etc. these also need to be identified.

I performed this task currently using Excel's fuzzy lookup add-on. which worked well but since the data is pretty large I needed to partition it in several smaller pieces. would have been nice to have similar tool in R

Answer (score 0):

You could try `amatch` function of package `stringdist`, e.g. :

```
library(stringdist)

toSearch <- c("1-PAGE LTD","3I GROUP PLC","3I INFOTECH LTD","401 HOLDINGS LTD",
              "4CS HOLDINGS CO LTD", "55 STATION INC","600 GROUP PLC (THE)",
              "7DIGITAL GROUP PLC")

lookupTable <- c("1-Page Ltd", "180 Connect Inc", "3DLabs Inc., Ltd.",
                 "3M France","3U Holdings AG", "4Imprint Group Plc", "724 Solutions Inc",
                 "7days music entertainment AG")

acceptableDistanceThresh = 0.23
lookupTableIndex <- amatch(toupper(toSearch),
                           toupper(lookupTable),
                           method='jw',
                           maxDist=acceptableDistanceThresh,
                           nthread = 4)


res <- data.frame(toSearch,
                  lookupTableValue=lookupTable,
                  lookupTableIndex=lookupTableIndex)

> res
                 toSearch   lookupTableValue lookupTableIndex
1          1-PAGE LTD         1-Page Ltd                1
2        3I GROUP PLC               <NA>               NA
3     3I INFOTECH LTD               <NA>               NA
4    401 HOLDINGS LTD     3U Holdings AG                5
5 4CS HOLDINGS CO LTD               <NA>               NA
6      55 STATION INC               <NA>               NA
7 600 GROUP PLC (THE)               <NA>               NA
8  7DIGITAL GROUP PLC 4Imprint Group Plc                6
```

In base package there's function `agrep` which can to perform partial matching, but it's not vectorized and not multithreaded.

Comment: What does LookupTable[res] refer to in the assignment of res?

Comment: @Yiyo: just a typo